# I am getting an error from Facebook in my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I am creating an image from my Facebook application. I am getting the following error from Facebook.

> CurlException: 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0),
>   errno 104

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you post the code that generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, or knowing if there is an actual issue w/ your SSL certificate (which you should NOT ignore), try something like this as a workaround:

```
<?php

$retry=False;

do {

   try {
     //your code goes here
     $retry=False;
     }

  catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
     $retry=True;
     }
  }
  while ($retry);

?>
```